# Get user avatar from user ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm currently developing a birthday announcing bot using discord.js. I wanted to show the avatar of the user, using their Discord user ID to then be used in an embed.

Using `client.fetchUser('[userID]').avatarURL` currently isn't working.

```
const exampleEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setAuthor(' Birthday Announcement:')
    .setThumbnail(cleint.fetchUser('[userID]').avatarURL)
    .setDescription(' Happy day of birth [user ID]! ')
    .setFooter('May 25');

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('f.test')) {
        message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
    }
});
```

It will send the embed alright without the image, but it will give a `throw er` every few seconds afterwards.

Comment: What's the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Client.fetchUser()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=fetchUser) returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Essentially, you have to wait for it to return a value. You can do so using the keyword [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) or by attaching a [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method to the promise. However, you also should catch any errors in the event of a rejected promise with a [`catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) method or [`try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) statement.

I'd suggest reading up on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) MDN documentation for more about asynchronous programming in JavaScript.

Example 1:

```js
// This needs to be inside of an async function to use 'await'
const { displayAvatarURL } = await client.fetchUser('id')
  .catch(console.error);

embed.setThumbnail(displayAvatarURL);
```

Example 2:

```js
client.fetchUser('id')
  .then(user => {
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL);
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

*In these examples, I'm using [`displayAvatarURL`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=displayAvatarURL) because it will return a default avatar URL if the user doesn't have theirs set.*

Answer (score 1):

After trying many solutions, I managed to make this code for my own use.

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
let thanos = client.users.fetch('IDHERE');
thanos.then(function(result1) {
    //put your code that uses the result1 (the user object) here
    //for example, you could do var imgURL = result1.displayAvatarURL();
});
```