# How to get voter profile with Top.gg SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to show those who voted for my bot from Top.gg like in the picture But I don't know how to get the profile picture. I have printed the 'req.vote' object in the console log, but I see something like this. How can I view the profile photo of the voter?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'd need a reference to the actual user themselves, you can use the `user` ID you have there for this. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56637052/get-user-avatar-from-user-id) on how to obtain the avatar by ID from there.

Comment: But if the user is not on my server or is not using my bot it will not appear.

Comment: @DevFatih It's unlikely anyone who isn't using the bot would vote for it. There isn't any other way to go about getting the avatar of someone who isn't using the bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Skully](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8982034/skully) suggested, you can fetch the [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) from the API using the [`fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch) method of [`UserManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager).

It does not matter if the [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) is in a server or not with your bot.

---

Here's an example of how to do it:

```js
client.users.fetch("123456789012345678").then(user => {
    console.log(`Found ${user.tag}.`);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log("Couldn't find the user.");
});
```